# Not able to change fabricjs Rectangle corner radius run time

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am not able to change Fabricjs rectangle corner radius runtime in new fabricjs 1.7 version.

It was working in previous version (v1.6) but does not work in current version.

**Sample code**

```
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();

var val = $('#cornerRadius').val();

activeObject.set({'rx': val,'ry':val});

activeObject.setCoords();

canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: Could you provide a Codepen?

Comment: URL: https://jsfiddle.net/vijaygurjar/g74x6o0a/34/

Change corner radius and enter then no effect in rectangle, but when you scale then after scaling corner radius changed. Issue with new fabricjs 1.7 version it was working in previous version

Comment: Have you included the fabric.js via cdn or as file. The fabric.js link in this jsfiddle is over http and therefore blocked

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xzkpLcw0/ works for me now. Check my answer with the https cdn link

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you included fabric.js over http

Use https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.3/fabric.min.js instead

Comment: Thanks for your help to use  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.3/fabric.min.js.

My problem is when apply corner radius then it is not directly reflected in shape but when i scale that shape object then it will apply.|
In my example pls change corner radius from input box and then change scaling of that object by mouse and check result new corner radius apply on shape. I need this result when i will change radius from input.